# Codeigniter: Two table query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables that I want to query. One table has records from the clinic while the other has records from the lab. This results in(Message: Trying to get property of non-object). What am I missing out?

I want to see the PID which are in clinic table but not in lab table.

My controller:

```
function queries(){
    $data['results'] = $this->main_model->queries();
    $this->load->view('queries', $data);

}
```

My Model:

```
function queries(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('clinic');
    $this->db->where('participantID NOT IN (SELECT  participantID FROM lab)', NULL, FALSE);
    $results = $this->db->get();
    return $results;
}
```

Finally, my view:

```
<?php 

foreach($results as $row){


echo " <tr > <td> $row->participantID </td>  <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td></tr>";


} 

?>
```

Comment: Use $row["participantID"] instead.

Comment: The problem lies in your model. you are returning an object rather than the array results. You have to do this: `$q= $this->db->get();  return $q->result();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
function getall(){      
$this->load->model('result_model');
$data['query'] =$this->result_model->result_getall();
print_r($data['query']);
die();
$this->load->view('result_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function result_getall(){

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblanswers');
$this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

}
```

view:

```
 <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>      

     <?php echo $row->answerA;?><br>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your model. You are not returning the proper array results. You have to first use `get()` to build the query and place it into a variable like `$q`, then use that variable with a the `result()` method to obtain the results, like this :

```
$q = $this->db->get(); 
return $q->result();
```